# Why is SQLAlchemy adding more rows than class instances in my program?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a class `GeneList` which is a list of `Gene` instances and another class `GeneSignature` which is a `GeneList` plus metadata. For some reason, the number of genes in my gene list changes *after* I add and commit the list to the database. For example:

```
print(len(gene_signature.gene_list)) # 204
session.add(gene_signature)
session.commit()
print(len(gene_signature.gene_list)) # 362
```

Oddly enough, this only happens when I'm connected to my development database, which does not have foreign key constraints setup. If I perform the same `add`/`commit` with the same input data but connected to my production database with proper foreign key constraints, the numbers are `204` and then `204`, as expected.

I thought that foreign key constraints are only for data integrity. What could possibly cause this?

**EDIT:**

I've setup foreign keys and the problem resolved itself. Why?

Comment: How did you create the first version of `gene_signature.gene_list`? It would also help if you switch on sqlalchemy logging to see what's going on, e.g. as: `logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`

Comment: I first create `GeneList`, do some filtering (i.e. removing `Gene` instances from the list) and then pass the modified list to the `GeneSignature` constructor.

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what's going on without looking at your model definitions, but this generally happens when you already have data in your database. Perhaps the `GeneSignature` already exists, or perhaps the `gene_list` already had some items that were not properly removed.

Comment: I used phpMyAdmin to create the foreign keys and accidentally created an internal relation instead. Once I created true foreign keys instead of internal relations, the issue has resolved itself.